# How to add an upload FileField in the Silverstripe User Forms module

Tags: file-upload, silverstripe, userform

I have a Silverstripe website where the admins can create online forms using the [userform module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/).

On an older website I do work for the userform has a form option for 'File Upload Field'.

On my current website I've downloaded the latest version of the userform module but the option for file upload is not listed in the form options.  Does anyone know what I'm missing/ what I need to do to give admins the ability to add a file uploader to the page?

Here's an image of the available options,
[Silverstripe form dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzCxR.png)

Comment: The is a `File Upload Field` option in the the latest version of the user forms module.

Comment: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/blob/master/code/model/editableformfields/EditableFileField.php

Comment: @3dgoo I see that page in my files but it's not showing up in the available options.  I've added a link in the original post to a screenshot of the options I can see.

Comment: That is strange. I am using the latest version of the User Forms module and I can see that field in the available options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `EditableFileField` currently requires the [`Secure Assets Module`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-secureassets) to work. If the Secure Assets Module is not installed, the `File Upload Field` does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

For Silverstripe Userforms module 4.5 and Silverstripe 3.6, if you really really don't want to install Secure Assets Module to enable File upload field just as me, you can create a `secureassets.yml` file in `mysite/_config` folder and add some yml configuration as below:

```
---
Name: userformsnosecurityoverride
After:
  - '#userformsnosecurity'
Except:
  ModuleExists: secureassets
---
EditableFileField:
  hidden: false
```

This will override the default settings and make the file upload field visible.